# Phase portrait of a constant coefficient system that has singular coefficient matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a basic 2d system $y' = Ay$ where $A$ is a constant coefficient matrix that happens to be singular. I'm used to drawing the phase portraits for non-singular matrices, so this one is throwing me for a loop.

I solved for the equilibrium: a set of points points along $y_1 = y_2$.

My eigenvalues are

$$\lambda_1 = 0 $$
$$\lambda_2 = -1$$

With eigenvectors (1,1) and (2,1), respectively.

I know that the negative eigenvalue indicates stability along its corresponding eigenvector. But the the other eigenvector is traced along the line of steady states.

I noticed that the solution tends towards that line of steady states $y_1 = y_2$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. I'm not sure how to interpret all these little bits of information to draw a correct phase portrait.

Comment: The first eigenvector is just along the line of equilibria, the second one gives you the direction along which each trajectory approaches a point on the line from both sides. It is a boring phase portrait. Imagine a 1D system with a single stable equilibrium point. Now stack identical such lines on top of each other until they fill the plane. It is a deformed version of that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider first the system with $A=\operatorname{diag}(-1,0)$. The general solution is $(c_1e^{-t},c_2)^T$. It should be reasonably obvious that the trajectories of these solutions follow lines parallel to the $x$-axis (i.e., in the direction of the eigenvectors of $-1$) and approach the $y$-axis—the line through the origin defined by the eigenvectors of $0$—as $t\to\infty$. Generalizing to a coefficient matrix with those eigenvalues, the trajectories will be lines parallel to the eigenvectors of $-1$, moving toward the eigenspace of $0$.